# JavaScript color Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I watched a codecademy video and have been unable to randomize my color array.  The colors are not random. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
    function getRandomColor() {
    var color;
    var colorArray = [
        "#FF6633",
        "#FFB399",
        "#FF33FF",
        "#FFFF99",
        "#00B3E6",
        "#E6B333",
        "#3366E6",
        "#999966",
        "#809980",
        "#E6FF80",
        "#1AFF33",
        "#999933",
        "#FF3380",
        "#CCCC00",
        "#66E64D",
        "#4D80CC",
        "#FF4D4D",
        "#99E6E6",
        "#6666FF"
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < colorArray; i++) {
        color = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by randomizing your color array?
Right now your code iterates over all colors and then returns the last one that was randomly selected.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why you need the `for` loop but I am quite sure that it is wrong.

## What is the problem?

In your case, the loop won't be executed because `colorArray`(in the condition) is not a number. You may wanted to use `colorArray.length` instead but there is no point for the loop in that case too.

## select one random color

If you just want to select *one* color, you can just replace the whole loop (and the `return` statement) with:

```
return colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
```

This will just return a random color.

## shuffle it

If you want to shuffle the whole array, you could use the following loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
    let r=Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length);
    color = colorArray[r];
    colorArray[r]=colorArray[i];
    colorArray[i]=color;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to shuffle the array itself (_"...and have been unable to randomize my color **array**_")

Answer (score 1):

add `length` to your loop `for (var i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++)`

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var color;
    var colorArray = [
       "#FF6633",
       "#FFB399",
       "#FF33FF",
       "#FFFF99",
       "#00B3E6",
       "#E6B333",
       "#3366E6",
       "#999966",
       "#809980",
       "#E6FF80",
       "#1AFF33",
       "#999933",
       "#FF3380",
       "#CCCC00",
       "#66E64D",
       "#4D80CC",
       "#FF4D4D",
       "#99E6E6",
       "#6666FF"
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
       color = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the ".length" on your for loop. `for(var i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shuffle the array you can use the following function:

```js
var colorArray = ["#FF6633", "#FFB399", "#FF33FF", "#FFFF99", "#00B3E6", "#E6B333", "#3366E6", "#999966", "#809980", "#E6FF80", "#1AFF33", "#999933", "#FF3380", "#CCCC00", "#66E64D", "#4D80CC", "#FF4D4D", "#99E6E6", "#6666FF"];

function shuffleArray() {
  colorArray.sort(function() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
  });
}

shuffleArray();
console.log(colorArray);
```

If you just want to get a random item you can do:

```js
var colorArray = ["#FF6633", "#FFB399", "#FF33FF", "#FFFF99", "#00B3E6", "#E6B333", "#3366E6", "#999966", "#809980", "#E6FF80", "#1AFF33", "#999933", "#FF3380", "#CCCC00", "#66E64D", "#4D80CC", "#FF4D4D", "#99E6E6", "#6666FF"];

function getRandomColor() {
  return colorArray[Math.random() * colorArray.length | 0];
}

console.log(getRandomColor());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a function which randomise.

```
function randomizeArr () {
   const randomLength=Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArr.length);
   return colorArr[randomLength];
}
```

And in your **for-loop** your condition is wrong it should have been `i < colorArr.length` instead of `colorArr`.

Generally **arr.length** is a **property it not a method** like `map()` or `reduce()` etc.

Hope my answer is clear!

Answer (score 0):

This program produces a random background color by pressing a button. The colors are "X11 colors" from the CSS3 specification [WebColors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors). I manually loaded these colors to the array, which is hopefully useful information for somebody. Of course, you can probably create the same array by doing a webscrape has anybody done this.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

var items = ['MediumVioletRed', 'DeepPink', 'PaleVioletRed', 'HotPink', 
   'LightPink', 'Pink', 'DarkRed', 'Red', 'Firebrick', 'Crimson', 
   'IndianRed', 'LightCoral', 'Salmon', 'DarkSalmon', 
   'LightSalmon', 'OrangeRed', 'Tomato', 'DarkOrange', 'Coral', 
   'Orange', 'DarkKhaki', 'Gold', 'Khaki', 'PeachPuff', 'Yellow', 
   'PaleGoldenrod', 'Moccasin', 'PapayaWhip', 'LightGoldenrodYellow', 
   'LemonChiffon', 'LightYellow','Maroon', 'Brown', 'SaddleBrown', 'Sienna', 
   'Chocolate', 'DarkGoldenrod', 'Peru', 'RosyBrown', 'Goldenrod', 
   'SandyBrown', 'Tan', 'Burlywood', 'Wheat', 'NavajoWhite', 'Bisque', 
   'BlanchedAlmond', 'Cornsilk','DarkGreen', 'Green', 'DarkOliveGreen', 
   'ForestGreen', 'SeaGreen', 'Olive', 'OliveDrab', 'MediumSeaGreen', 
   'LimeGreen', 'Lime', 'SpringGreen', 'MediumSpringGreen', 'DarkSeaGreen', 
   'MediumAquamarine', 'YellowGreen', 'LawnGreen', 'Chartreuse', 'LightGreen', 
   'GreenYellow', 'PaleGreen', 'Teal', 'DarkCyan', 'LightSeaGreen', 
   'CadelBlue', 'DarkTurquoise', 'MediumTurquoise', 'Turquoise', 'Aqua', 
   'Cyan', 'AquaMarine', 'PaleTurquoise', 'LightCyan', 'Navy', 'DarkBlue', 
   'MediumBlue', 'Blue', 'MidnightBlue', 'RoyalBlue', 'SteelBlue', 
   'DodgerBlue', 'DeepSkyBlue', 'CornFlowerBlue', 'SkyBlue', 'LightSkyBlue', 
   'LightSteelBlue', 'LightBlue', 'PowderBlue', 'Indigo', 'Purple', 
   'DarkMagenta', 'DarkViolet', 'DarkSlateBlue', 'BlueViolet', 'DarkOrchid', 
   'Fuchsia', 'Magenta', 'SlateBlue', 'MediumSlateBlue', 
   'MediumOrchid', 'MediumPurple', 'Orchid', 'Violet', 'Plum', 
   'Thistle', 'Lavender', 'MistyRose', 'AntiqueWhite', 'Linen', 
   'Beige', 'WhiteSmoke', 'LavenderBlush', 'OldLace', 'AliceBlue', 
   'Seashell', 'GhostWhite', 'Honeydew', 'ForalWhite', 'Azure', 
   'MintCream', 'Snow', 'Ivory', 'White', 'Black', 'DarkSlateGray', 
   'DimGray', 'SlateGrey', 'Gray', 'LightSlateGray', 'DarkGray', 
   'Silver', 'LightGray', 'Gainsboro'];

function random_item(items)
{
  
    return items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
     
}



btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   const rndWebCol = (random_item(items));

   document.body.style.backgroundColor = rndWebCol;
  
   console.log(rndWebCol);
  
});
```

Comment: This program produces a random background color by pressing a button. The colors are  "X11 colors" from the CSS3 specification [WebColors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors). I manually loaded these colors to the array, which is hopefully useful information for somebody. Of course, you can probably create the same array by doing a webscrape has anybody done this.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below your post to add information instead of posting in the comments